C# Aspire configure CORS
I'm relatively new to setting up CORS in ASP.NET Core, and I'm running into some issues. I need to configure CORS for the Aspire orchestrator, but I'm not entirely sure how to do it correctly. I would really appreciate any advice or examples that could help me set it up properly for my project. Thanks in advance!
I tried adding a basic CORS configuration in the Startup.cs file of my ASP.NET Core project, allowing all origins, methods, and headers. I realize that this might not be the most appropriate solution, and I need to find a more suitable way to configure CORS for this scenario.
I need to clarify that this is specifically for projects launched by Aspire.

I realize that this might not be the most appropriate solution. Do you want to configure the CORS policy for a specific endpoint? Or do you want to allow CORS configuration on the OTLP HTTP endpoint?

And in .NET Aspire there can be multiple apps + the one that serves as monitoring tools (dashboard) - what applicaiton do you mean exactly?

var webClient = builder
    .AddNpmApp("client", "../../path", "dev")
    .WithEnvironment("BROWSER", "none")
    .WithHttpEndpoint(env: "VITE_PORT")
    .WithExternalHttpEndpoints();

// #2
var api= builder.AddProject<Projects.Api_Web>("api")
    .WithReference(db)
    .WithReference(webClient)
    .WithExternalHttpEndpoints();

// #3 
var endpoint = api.GetEndpoint("http");
webClient.WithEnvironment("VITE_API", endpoint);

In this sequence, everything works as I want it to.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
